# Parsing /dev/input/mouse0 for Multi-Touch

Tags: linux, multi-touch, xorg, touchpad

I need to enable gesture detection (in userspace) from a multi-touch synaptics touch pad on linux.  Reading from the mouse device file (/dev/input/mouse0) for the touchpad, I've figured out that it's the PS/2 protocol.

In short, thats 1 bit for:
XY sign and overflow, 3 mouse buttons, and a permanent '1'
Followed by 1 byte for the X delta and Y delta.

That totals 3 bytes. But I don't see any way to detect which finger a packet 'belongs' to when 
more than one finger is on the touch pad.  Suggestions?

Comment: Not positive, but I believe you need to use the event interface, not the mouse interface.

Comment: Two links of possible value: http://bitmath.org/code/mtdev/ and http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt

Answer (score 2):

That's not the right way to do it.  The mouse device file you are seeing is emulating a standard mouse.

You will need to detect multi touch events.  See:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Testing/CheckingMTDevice